# How to enforce Large Text in GNOME Web?

Tags: accessibility, epiphany

When I enable *Large Text* in a GNOME/Wayland desktop session it works in most applications. In GNOME Web it's a bit different:

- browser chrome gets bigger
- some websites get bigger (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page )
- some websites stay the same (e.g. https://arstechnica.com )

I get around this in Mozilla-based browsers by setting `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` which embiggers everything (ref. https://superuser.com/a/1268867)

In GNOME Web there's a GUI tool to zoom in which has the same effect, but the effect does not persist and does not get applied to all tabs/sites. How can I make it persistent and universal?

Comment: related https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=796134

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a direct equivalent for GNOME Web:

- Open the dconf editor
- Navigate to org/gnome/epiphany/web/default-zoom-level
- Set the value (for example 1.25)

[image: Setting the default zoom level in dconf editor]

Hat tip: https://askubuntu.com/questions/207151